# Python: extract the text string from a DataFrame to a long string

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame`: `df1` as following.

```
   date                  text                             name
     1      I like you hair, do you like it              screen1
     2      beautiful sun and wind                       screen2
     3      today is happy, I want to got school         screen3
     4      good movie                                   screen4
     5      thanks god                                   screen1
```

I want to make a long text string from the text column values in the `df1`. And the expected result will be as shown below:

```
    str_long = "I like you hair, do you like it beautiful sun and     
     wind today is happy, I want to got school good movie thanks god"
```

Could anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.str.cat()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas.Series.str.cat) method of a data frame column ([`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#series) object):

```
df["text"].str.cat(sep=" ")
```

You can apply `str.join()` on a data frame column as well:

```
" ".join(df["text"])
```

---

Or, you can just call [`sum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum) on the `Series` instance (you may lose the spaces between each individual strings in this case though):

```
df["text"].sum()
```

Comment: thanks for comments. if I want to join all the text which name is just screen1. How to do it? thanks!

Comment: @tktktk0711 sure, `df[df['name'] == 'screen1']["text"].str.cat(sep=" ")`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `tolist()`

```
' '.join(df['text'].tolist())
```

**Explanation:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [1, 2, 3], 'text': ['I like your', 'beautiful sun', 'good movie']})

df
Out[68]: 
   date           text
0     1    I like your
1     2  beautiful sun
2     3     good movie

' '.join(df['text'].tolist())
Out[72]: 'I like your beautiful sun good movie'
```

Comment: I just saw @alecxe 's answer, looks like you can directly join the `pd.Series` without needing the `tolist()`! That makes thing even more easier.